# Resizing Layout equal to MainWindow

Tags: qt, layout

When I run my program it will display all content properly, and when I resizing the main window, the layout along with all associated widgets remain fixed, rather than resizing with the main window. I used to increase my all widget and listWidget respect to window computer resolution size but still this not one work properly.
I used this one code finding the system height and width.

```
    QWidget widget;
    widget.resize(widget.width(), widget.minimumHeight());
    QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
    int h = rec.height();
    int w = rec.width();
    // Increasing the listwidget size
    ui->listWidget->setFixedHeight(h);
    ui->listWidget->setFixedWidth(w);
   //increasing the button size
    ui->pushButton->setFixedHeight(h0.2);
    ui->pushButton->setFixedWidth(w0.2);
```

At this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBgJ0.jpg) you will find two screenshots that illustrate my problem.

Please resolve to solve my problem. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Looks like your window is not given a QLayout (vertical, horizontal or grid) for its widgets. It would be useful to have a screenshot from Qt designer that shows the Object Inspector (the panel on the top right corner with columns "Object" and "Class") with the tree of all the widgets in your form.

Comment: When I make a grid .. Inside the content like list widget and tab widget size does not display properly. I am adding the google drive link for image reference please view it

Comment: @AmarYadav provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=17Zy82FAtan1VT7Bbp6NYMGUo7Oxx3xip

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sNNrI68HXaSpGIy4gfEhwLGfIxtu43-M

Comment: @Amar Yadav the links provided require a login. For your safety do not give access to anyone to your drive space. Instead edit your question and add the images like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation for uploading an image

Comment: @Amar Yadav I see. Can you edit your question to copy and paste the contents of your .ui file? I hope it's not too long... :)

Comment: too long file .... can u please give me ur mail id so, I will show you my image image

Comment: @Amar Yadav No, sorry. Use this site to upload the images https://imgur.com/ (no login, no account required). Then edit your question adding the links.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4mwUkhn

Comment: @Grbriella Giordano Just see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining the layout of your windows and forms in Qt Designer you have to define each element of your form in advance, in order to have a working layout.

This solution is based on the screenshots provided in the comments to the question. Follow these steps:

1. Add an empty widget to the central area of your form, if there is nothing there. It will be used as a placeholder for the controls you will add later, and of course you can replace it with whatever widget you want. But you need it there to define a proper layout.
2. In the property panel, set the horizontal [QSizePolicy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) of this widget to MinimumExpanding.
3. Add an [horizontal spacer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspaceritem.html) to the left side of your progress bar.
4. Define a minimum/maximum width for the white widget on the left (I guess it's a text area). As an example set the maximum width to 200
   pixels.
5. Make the same for the QTabWidget on the right.
6. Give a minimum height to the Groupbox on top.
7. Then give the grid layout to the MainWindow.

You should get something similar in the designer view (I use a dark theme, yours will have different colors of course):

[image: Qt Designer screenshot]

If you complete all steps you should have a nicely resizing window.

For the future: remember to integrally define your layouts, also using placeholder widgets when needed, read carefully the documentation about the widgets size policies (there are several, you need to play with them to fully understand each one) and keep in mind that Qt uses a container based approach which is different, as an example from those used by the .Net framework that relies on the concept of anchors.

EDIT : to answer questions in the comments

You will need to add a layout to any widget that contains other widgets, e.g. adding controls to your groupbox will require to give it a grid, horizontal or vertical layout in order to scale nicely on resize. Again use spacers and size policies to make it look the way you want. If you need to add or remove controls, or change their positions, you may need to brake the layout, rearrange and then set it again.

You can also select groups of widgets and give them a layout e.g. vertical, than another group and set them horizontal and so on... then give a grid layout to the container widget to build a compound layout.

There are endless possibilities, you just need to practice and go through trial and error as for everything else...

You can also do it all programmatically, check the Qt widgets documentation for this. But for complex layouts I would not go that way: it's a lot of code... and you have to compile and run to test every modification.

Comment: Thank you its working .... but i have another problem is there .... When i will added more group box inside the groupBox then new groupBox not maximize equal to the Bigger group box

Comment: Can I do the same procedure with coding? WIthout using manually, through using dynamically

Comment: @Amar Yadav You're welcome :) Another tip (maybe you already know): to test the layout you do not need to compile and run. Just use Tools -> Form Editor -> Preview. It's there just to test basic widget behavior (also resizing) and layouting.

Comment: Thanks again. I really don't know this one to preview the layout

Comment: I have some doubt related to my viewer. When I apply the Grid layout for the main window, the grid separation by default take some size between the two widgets. Can any way to remove the extra space.

Comment: Yes, probably you need to change the spacing of the grid layout. You can do it from the widget property panel (bottom right corner), when the centralWidget item of your Mainwindow selected. Look for the spacing properties, and set the desired value.

Comment: Giordano For MainWindow I am not able to remove space. For groupBox i will remove the space but not for central widget.

Answer (score 0):

Using the QtCreator, within the designer you can simply right-click on the parent-widget and add a Grid-Layout.
This one resizes it's children to it's dimensions.

Comment: But I want to resize children size manually but when I use to make centralwidget as a grid layout all the grid children size they were taken by default.